# How do I perform cascading deletes on my entities in this situation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How do I get entity framework to delete Fields and Events (defined below) from an EsignatureDocument without it causing an error? I suspect that there is some model building code I could write that is executed at the application start in the DbContext, using EntityTypeConfiguration... What would builder code be for the following example.

I have a short piece of C# that does work. Here it is:

```
    var document = _repo.Load<EsignatureDocument>(input.EsignatureDocumentId);

document.Events.Clear();

                document.Fields.Clear();

            _repo.SaveChanges();
```

When I call it, I receive the following error:

> The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the
>   foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a
>   relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value.
>   If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship
>   must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another
>   non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

The entity framework classes are as follows:

```
  [Table("EsignatureDocument", Schema = "dbo")]
    public class EsignatureDocument 
    {
        public EsignatureDocument()
        {
            Events = new HashSet<EsignatureDocumentEvent>();
        }
public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(10)]
        public string DocumentReference { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(300)]
        public string EnvelopeTitle { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string Path { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string SignedPath { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public string SignedUrl { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public string SignableUrl { get; set; }
        public DateTime? SignedDate { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(32)]
        public string EnvelopeFingerprint { get; set; }
        public bool SentByEmail { get; set; }
        public bool SentBySms { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string LetterReference { get; set; }
        public virtual HashSet<EsignatureDocumentEvent> Events { get; set; }
        public virtual HashSet<EsignatureDocumentField> Fields { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public bool IsSigned
        {
            get { return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SignedPath); }
        }

        [NotMapped]
        public EsignatureDocumentEvent LatestEvent 
        {
            get { return Events.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault(); } 
        }

    }

[Table("EsignatureDocumentEvent", Schema = "dbo")]
    public class EsignatureDocumentEvent : EntityBase
    {
        public Guid EsignatureDocumentId { get; set; }
        public SignableAction Action { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string ActionName { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string ActionDisplayName {
            get
            {
                return char.ToUpper(ActionName[0]) + ActionName.Substring(1).ToLower().Replace("_envelope", string.Empty);
            } 
        }
        public string FieldsJson { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(1000)]
        public string DocumentPdf { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    }

[Table("EsignatureDocumentField", Schema = "dbo")]
    public class EsignatureDocumentField  
    {
        [Key]
        public int Field_Id { get; set; }
        public string Field_Value { get; set; }
        public string Field_Name { get; set; }
        public string Field_Type { get; set; }
        public virtual EsignatureDocument EsignatureDocument { get; set; }
        public Guid EsignatureDocumentId { get; set; }
    }
```

Script for the child tables are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EsignatureDocumentEvent](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [EsignatureDocumentId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Action] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ActionName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FieldsJson] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [DocumentPdf] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EsignatureDocumentEvent] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO



  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EsignatureDocumentEvent]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_EsignatureDocumentEvent_EsignatureDocument] FOREIGN KEY([EsignatureDocumentId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[EsignatureDocument] ([Id])
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EsignatureDocumentEvent] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_EsignatureDocumentEvent_EsignatureDocument]
    GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EsignatureDocumentField](
    [Field_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Field_Name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Field_Value] [varchar](1000) NOT NULL,
    [Field_Type] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [EsignatureDocumentId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Field_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EsignatureDocumentField]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_EsignatureDocumentField_EsignatureDocument] FOREIGN KEY([EsignatureDocumentId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[EsignatureDocument] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EsignatureDocumentField] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_EsignatureDocumentField_EsignatureDocument]
GO
```

Comment: What happens if you call `RemoveAll(t => true)` instead of `Clear()`

Comment: There is no RemoveAll on HashSet<T> but when I do document.Fields.RemoveWhere(x => x.EsignatureDocumentId == input.EsignatureDocumentId); It still fails with the same error

Comment: When I change from HashSet to List and perform RemoveAll, I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Clear() removes the reference to the parent, not the child entity itself.

The problem is, when you call document.Fields.Clear(), it will nullify the EsignatureDocumentId column on the Field entity. This is not allowed since the EsignatureDocumentId is not nullable, so you can't have a field without a parent document.
Either you should mark the column as nullable, or you shoud use:

```
foreach(var f in document.Field) 
{
    Context.DeleteObject(f); //or fieldRepo.Delete(f) or something that fits for 
}
```